# What are the typical write throughput to s3 (using flume 0.9.4)

Tags: amazon-s3, throughput, flume

I am running my flume (flume 0.9.4-cdh3u4) flow in BE mode and both agent and collector, that are on separate machines, are large EC2 instances

The collector writes to the local filesystem as well as a S3 bucket in the same region.

The agent, when configured in E2E mode has been tested to handle 4MB/s and so is the agent <-> collector speed.

Using 'iftop' I notice that there are two outgoing connections by the collector to S3 and the write throughput to s3 hovers around 40KB/s - 50KB/s

1. What are the typical write throughput to s3 you have seen using the collector?
2. I was wondering if it would be possible to spawn more of these threads (that write to S3) to maximize the instance utilization?

How do I do that?

I would rather not spawn more collectors, if I could increase the write throughput another way.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having stuff pile up on the collector? Is it possible that 50KB/s is all the data that's being generated?

Are you using a roll sink? Roll sink will batch data to upload to S3. Larger roll size should improve throughput.

Comment: which config does one use to increase roll size?